# Postgres SQL string matching in where

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

What's the simplest way to write a SQL query (postgres) for the following:
I have an adress table, that has a streetnumber column. That can contain digits and  letters. And I if an argument is say '3' I want to return rows with values starting with three followed by something that is not a digit. So for example rows with streetnumber values 3, 3A, 3 A, but not 33.

Comment: BTW your question is actually violating SO's rules. Check the [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [matching using regular expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP).

The query may look like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE streetnumber ~ '3[^0-9]*'
```

The regular expression pattern `3[^0-9]*` matches "*digit 3 followed by zero or more characters which are not a digit*".

Comment: For the given example, a better regex would be `3\s*A`. The `\s*` meaning zero or more whitespaces in between.

Comment: Thanks, do you also no how I can parameterize it, that is in your example how the three can be replaces by say :addressNumber?

Also I think Dawid is write in that I want to ensure whitespaces matches.

Comment: @tyronecopex Well, the parametrizing depends on how you're constructing the query, i.e. where the value to be used is stored, what language/technology is used to construct the query.

Comment: @coladict My regex would match all cases OP mentioned in his question. Your regex wouldn't match for example "3A". I would leave it up to OP to pick what better fits his needs.

Comment: @tyronecopex So try to better describe your conditions and I'll try to further help you.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy Wrong. The `*` means zero or more times. You're confusing it with `+` which means one or more times.

Comment: @coladict I don't think so. A copy&paste from my answer: "_digit 3 followed by **zero or more** characters which are not a digit_".